# Creating an Array from NSObject Class

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsobject, nsmutableset

I have an NSObject class call Details that holds 3 properties.

```
 @interface Details : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, nonnull, strong) UIImage *image; 
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger number; 
@property (nonatomic, nonnull, strong) NSString *details;

- (NSDictionary *_Nonnull)getMappedDictionary; @end
```

And the impelentation of this class is

```
@interface Details()
@property (nonatomic, nonnull) NSString *imageFormat;
@property (nonatomic, nonnull) NSData *imageData;
@end

@implementation Details

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _imageFormat = @"jpg";
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSData *)imageData {
    if (!_imageData) {
        _imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1.0);
    }
    return _imageData;
}

- (NSInteger)number {
    return _number;
}

- (NSString *)details {
    return _details;
}

- (NSString *)getImageBase64 {
    NSString *base64String = @"";
    base64String = [self.imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
    return base64String;
}

static id ObjectOrNull(id object) {
    return object ?: [NSNull null];
}

- (NSDictionary *)getMappedDictionary {
    return @{ImageKey : ObjectOrNull([self getImageBase64]), NumberKey : @(_number), DetailKey : _details};
}
```

In another class call Request Class i would like to create an array to hold Details class's properties (image, number, details)

```
- (NSMutableSet<Details *> *)details {
    if (!_details) {
        _details = [NSMutableSet new];
    }
    return _dDetails;
}

- (NSArray *)getMappedActionDetails {
    NSMutableArray *details = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (Details *detail in self.details) {
        [details addObject:[detail getMappedDictionary]];
    }
    return details;
}
```

But i can not able to have this class's properties as an array... What am i missing here? Any help would be perfect! Thanks

Comment: But what is the issue? This all looks good to me.

Comment: reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'.   this is what i am keep getting i can not go into this `[details addObject:[actionDetail getMappedDictionary]];` @MaticOblak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

means that you create a dictionary with nil. 
objects[0] means your fist object is nil.
so I guess that when you create a dictionary by this.

```
- (NSDictionary *)getMappedDictionary {
     return @{ImageKey : ObjectOrNull([self getImageBase64]), NumberKey : @(_number), DetailKey : _details};
}
```

`ObjectOrNull([self getImageBase64])` return a nil.

Comment: Yes i fixed that part no crash now but can not able to create nsarray still.. getMappedDictionary method from Detail class is not showing me anything when i call in Request class it keeps getting as nil. @MaticOblak

Comment: Is it because the `details` attribute in the `Request` class is empty? so when you call `for (Details *detail in self.details) { [details addObject:[detail getMappedDictionary]];}`. self.details is an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems the issue is in fact trying to inset a nil object into dictionary:

> '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]:
>   attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

The code that is provided would point to `getMappedActionDetails` which is most likely inserting a `nil` object. Assuming `ObjectOrNull` does what it implies I would wager that in one of your models `_details` property is `nil`. Maybe the fix is:

```
- (NSDictionary *)getMappedDictionary {
    return @{ImageKey : ObjectOrNull([self getImageBase64]), NumberKey : @(_number), DetailKey : ObjectOrNull(_details)};
}
```

I also suggest using [exception breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802942/526828) to get the exact location of the crash.